# Getting php mails, but don't want to receive them when not all information is filled out

Tags: php, forms, email, spam-prevention

```
    PHP

<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_subject = $_POST['cf_subject'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'wermedia@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Melding fra nettsiden: '.$field_subject;
$mail_noreply = 'noreply@wermedia.com';

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Subject: '.$field_subject."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = "From: $field_name <$field_email> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: .$field_email.\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: .$field_email.\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: Drupal \n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

$confirmationSubject='Confirmation message';
$displayForm=true;

if ($_POST){
$field_email=stripslashes($_POST['cf_email']);
$field_message=stripslashes($_POST['cf_message']);
// validate e-mail address
$valid=eregi('^([0-9a-z]+[-._+&])*[0-9a-z]+@([-0-9a-z]+[.])+[a-z]{2,6}$',$field_email);
$crack=eregi("(\r|\n)(to:|from:|cc:|bcc:)",$field_message);
if ($field_email && $field_message && $valid && !$crack){
if (mail($mail_to,$confirmationSubject,$bodymessage.$field_message,'From: '.$mail_noreply."\r\n")){
$displayForm=false;
?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Your message was successfully sent. In addition, a confirmation copy was sent to your e-mail address.');
        window.location = 'contact.htm';
    </script>
<?php
        echo '<script>'.htmlspecialchars($field_message).'</script>';
      }else{ // the messages could not be sent
?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Something went wrong when the server tried to send your message. This is usually due to a server error, and is probably not your fault. We apologise for any inconvenience caused. Click OK and go one step back, to see your message.');
        window.location = 'contact.htm';
    </script>
<?php
      }
    }else if ($crack){ // cracking attempt
?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Your message contained e-mail headers within the message body. This seems to be a cracking attempt and the message has not been sent. Click OK and go one step back, to see your message.');
        window.location = 'contact.htm';
    </script>
<?php
    }else{ // form not complete
?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Your message could not be sent. You must include both a valid e-mail address and a message. Click OK and go one step back, to see your message.');
        window.location = 'contact.htm';
    </script>
<?php
    }
  }
?>

HTML

<form action="contact.php" method="post">
  Name<br>
  <input id="phpinput" type="text" name="cf_name"><br>
  Subject<br>
  <input id="phpinput" type="text" name="cf_subject"><br>
  E-mail<span style="color: red">*</span><br>
  <input id="phpinput" type="text" name="cf_email"><br>
  Message<span style="color: red">*</span><br>
  <textarea name="cf_message"></textarea><br>
  <input class="mob_sendclear" style="font-family: bankgothic;" type="submit" value="Send">
  <input class="mob_sendclear" style="font-family: bankgothic;" type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

I feel like it's all good, except that when you get the message that stuff is NOT OK, I still receive the mail... So if you send a mail and get a error message, I still receive a mail in my inbox.

Can someone tell me what to do, and where?

I also want to put a simple but pretty secure anti-spam code.

Answer (score -1):

just validate clientside

jquery-validate
or use backbone-forms
with build in validation,

generally this is a frontend and not a php issue,
and serverside validation for mails is
a little bit overkill, because for every false submit
you ring your serverside wich is business 2 nobody,
personally its better for the user performance to have most of the
stuff on the clientside, just my opinion